# Object recognition kitchen capture orb_template

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!

I'm trying to use the ORK on ubuntu 12.04 with ros Hydro.
I installed it using sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-object-recognition-*. I did **not install couchapp** (sudo pip install -U couchapp), as, if I understood well, it is not necessary.
Now, following this [tutorial](http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/quickguide.html#setup-the-capture-workspace), I have a kinect connected to my computer and running:

```
rosrun openni_launch openni.launch
```

works properly, as I can see the depth image with image_view.
However, when I try to use the command:

```
rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_template -o my_textured_plane
```

what happens is that the depth image that appears is all black and the ORB window all red. Moreover I noticed that if I try to run this command with the image_view running and showing the depth image, the image_view stops to be updated, i.e. the openni.launch doesn't publish anymore the /camera/depth/image topic. Also when I stop running the orb_template command, the depth image topic still isn't published.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!!

EDIT:

this is the output of the command `rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_template -o my_textured_plane`

```
Listening for key: s on imshow:save
Registration? 1
Sync? 0
1. device on bus: 2 @ 6 with serial number: A00365A03335051A  Microsoft : Xbox NUI Camera
Time diff max: 16.8667
Registered:on Supported: 1
Setting registration on
Setting sync off
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110031/object-recognition-kitchen-capture-orb_template/) by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 808 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using a 32 bit Ubuntu? Then it is a known Bug. Just install 64 bit Ubuntu and move on! See https://github.com/wg-perception/capture/issues/15#issuecomment-30496760

Greets,
O3

---

Originally posted by [o3p7s5](https://answers.ros.org/users/9096/o3p7s5/) with karma: 86 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-12-15**:
That's it! Thank you! I will try it in a few days!